# Register global converters in jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have a snippet of code like:

```java
ctx.select()
   .from()
   ...
   .fetchInto(MyAwesomeClass.class)
```

`MyAwesomeClass` has a field with a custom type (let's call it `MyLong`), which can be converted to/from `Long`. Currently, jOOQ can't convert between `Long` and `MyLong`:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataTypeException: Cannot convert from 1 (class java.lang.Long) to class foo.bar.MyLong
```

I would like to register a converter in the jOOQ DSL configuration to convert from `Long` to `MyLong`. I have the converter, but I'm struggling to get it into the DSL configuration. There is the option to give the configuration a ConverterProvider, which I did - but it didn't seem to work.

The ConverterProvider snippet is something like this:

```java
new DefaultConfiguration()
    .set(
        new ConverterProvider() {
          @Override
          public <T, U> Converter<T, U> provide(Class<T> tType, Class<U> uType) {
            if (tType == Long.class && uType == MyLong.class) {
              return (Converter<T, U>) Converter.of(Long.class, MyLong.class, MyLong::of, MyLong::toLong);
            } else {
              throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
          }
        });
```

I know that this API is marked as experimental, but is there some other way to achieve what I want, without declaring a forced binding or some other construct on the code generation side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The `ConverterProvider` SPI

The [`ConverterProvider`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.6.0/org/jooq/ConverterProvider.html) SPI has been added in jOOQ 3.6, but this addition was not documented, nor has the SPI been implemented completely. The relevant, rejected issue is: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3896

The SPI types have not been removed yet due to backwards compatibility issues in the `Configuration` API (especially relevant when configured with Spring).

#### Current solution as of jOOQ 3.11

This SPI would have solved your problem indeed. Until a similar SPI is implemented, you need to register your custom `Converter` types with the fields that are part of your projection / `SELECT` clause. This can be done in two ways:

- **Using the code generator**

  You can register your own custom data types and the relevant converters easily using the [`<forcedTypes/>` configuration](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/) in your code generator. That way, whenever you select a converted column, jOOQ will produce your own custom type `MyLong` rather than the database / JDBC type `Long`

- **Using ad-hoc converted types**

  If you're not using the code generator, you can create your own data types like this:

  ```
  DataType<MyLong> MY_LONG_TYPE = SQLDataType.BIGINT.asConvertedDataType(new MyLongConverter());
  Field<MyLong> MY_LONG_FIELD = field(name("MY_TABLE", "MY_LONG_FIELD"), MY_LONG_TYPE);
  ```

  You can now use this column reference in any query to get `MyLong` values:

  ```
  ctx.select(MY_LONG_FIELD)
     .from(...)
     .fetchInto(MyAwesomeClass.class);
  ```

Comment: how will this apply for an insert/update statement please? I'm assuming that during the fetch, the converter will use the from(..) method and during an insert/update statement the to(..) method if the converter is used. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: @user1135357: Would you mind asking a new question with some more details?

Comment: sorry about that. Taking the example above, if I want to insert/update a record in MY_TABLE, how will the MyLongConverter be triggered in order to convert the MyLong value to a Long value (which is understood by the database)? Will the MyLongConverter.to(..) method be triggered in some way?

Comment: @user1135357: Yes, it will be "triggered". It will really be much simpler if you ask a new question with context, though. Don't worry. Stack Overflow won't run out of question IDs any time soon.